# Installing Canon Printer via VBScript/CMD

Tags: batch-file, printing, vbscript, cmd

I am trying to write a VBScript that installs a Canon LBP6780 Printer via IP address automatically when clicked.

I have a more complex script but the part I am having trouble with is the following line of code... although it is called from a VBS file, it's actually running a bit of cmd prompt code.

```
cmd /c rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "Store Printer" /f "CNLB0KA64.INF" /r "IP_10.17.9.50" /m "Canon iR 6870C EUR" /Z
```

To put it into better context, "Store Printer" is the new name of the printer i'm trying to add, "CNLB0KA64.INF" is the path to the driver file, `"IP_10.17.9.50"` is the IP address of the printer and "Canon iR 6870C EUR" is the name of the driver I want to use - it isn't the same driver as the printer but when manually adding the printer outside of code, this driver works.

I get this error code`0x00000002` when trying to run it.

Traditionally I have used the HP Laserjet 4100 Drivers as these are so generic that they work with a lot of printers but they don't seem to work with these printers. I don't get the error but it also doesn't print.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Error `0x00000002` is `Windows cannot connect to the printer` so it's not directly related to VBScript. If it works from the command line maybe compare the VBScript command *(`cmd /c rundll32 ...`)* string to make sure there are no differences *(missing quotes etc)* from the VBScript generated execution. If they are the same then it's likely a permissions issue maybe pointing to UAC or something similar.